# Security implications for email address and url changes?

Tags: email

recently, we are seeing some From:, To:, Cc: addresses being
rewritten from user1@companyA.com to:

https://3c-lxa.mail.com/mail/client/mail/mailto;jsessionid=36725F1B090973DAF815646A3B096862-n1.lxa15a?to=user1%40companyA.com

i've checked RFC 822, and 2822 and the above does not
seem to be valid address specification formats. 
Are there some other RFC or email clients that handles the
above links ?

Also, links in the emails of the form www.companyA.com are
also rewritten into:

www.companyA.comhttps://3c-lxa.mail.com/mail/client/dereferrer?redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.companyA.com%2F

what could have caused the above changes and what are the
implications ?

Comment: Where are you seeing them replaced as that?  Is it in the mail client or in the header itself?  It appears like the client is just parsing the e-mail and then replacing it with a link to part of the webmail interface.

Comment: Thanks AJ,
sorry for the late response, was away for a while.
i see it in email thread that the user forwarded to me..
looks like it is in the message headers ?
sam

Comment: Right, what kind of client are you viewing it in though?

Answer (score 1):

What program are you using to view the email?

It looks as if you are using the web interface from `mail.com` to read the email (mail.com is an email provider).

If this is the case, they are simply using an intermediate script as target of the addresses. When you click an address from the webmail, the goal is that the user writes a new email to that address, so it needs to be rewritten, instead of having the webmail opening a local MUA.

In the second case, where it is a http url, the name suggests that you are being redirected through https://3c-lxa.mail.com/mail/client/dereferrer?redirectUrl=… in order to conceal the url from which you were reading your email, as that might contain sensitive information, such as session tokens, your address, etc.

Comment: Thanks Angel,
sorry for the late response, was away for a while.
the users stopped pursuing it, so i have no more
accesses to them.
i'll remember the your very helpful info;
when they come back again, i'll ask the appropriate
questions ..
sam